# How to view the section layout info recorded in an ELF file?

Tags: ld, elf, objdump

Suppose the following linker script is used to *layout* an executable file.

```
SECTIONS
{
. = 0x10000;
.text : { *(.text) }
.data : { *(.data) }
.bss  : { *(.bss) }
}

OUTPUT_FORMAT(ELF)
```

My questions are:

1. I think such layout info must be stored in the output ELF file so the *loader* can load the executable based on that info. Right?
2. If 1 is true, how to view such layout info in a ELF? objdump?

Answer (score 2):

You can deduce the information from the linker command script by taking a look at the output of the `-S` option in `readelf`.

```
$ readelf -S $(which ls)
There are 28 section headers, starting at offset 0x1f6f8:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         0000000000400238  00000238
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             0000000000400254  00000254
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE             0000000000400274  00000274
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH         0000000000400298  00000298
       0000000000000104  0000000000000000   A       5     0     8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM           00000000004003a0  000003a0
       0000000000000c48  0000000000000018   A       6     1     8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB           0000000000400fe8  00000fe8
       0000000000000582  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM           000000000040156a  0000156a
...
```

If you want to know where this comes from, take a look at the default linker command scripts for your toolchain; this default is used if you did not explicitly create your own. I think there may be some inheritance between them as well, but I can't say for certain.

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/ldscripts/ | grep elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9027 Mar 22 04:05 elf32_x86_64.x
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8880 Mar 22 04:05 elf32_x86_64.xbn
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8706 Mar 22 04:05 elf32_x86_64.xc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9024 Mar 22 04:05 elf32_x86_64.xd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8720 Mar 22 04:05 elf32_x86_64.xdc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8680 Mar 22 04:05 elf32_x86_64.xdw
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9027 Mar 22 04:05 elf32_x86_64.xn
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5443 Mar 22 04:05 elf32_x86_64.xr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8551 Mar 22 04:05 elf32_x86_64.xs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8247 Mar 22 04:05 elf32_x86_64.xsc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8207 Mar 22 04:05 elf32_x86_64.xsw
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5489 Mar 22 04:05 elf32_x86_64.xu
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8666 Mar 22 04:05 elf32_x86_64.xw
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8396 Mar 22 04:05 elf_i386.x
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8249 Mar 22 04:05 elf_i386.xbn
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8209 Mar 22 04:05 elf_i386.xc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8389 Mar 22 04:05 elf_i386.xd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8219 Mar 22 04:05 elf_i386.xdc
...
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I think such layout info must be stored in the output ELF file so the loader can load the executable based on that info. Right?

`ELF` stands for executable and linking format.

The `.text`, `.data` etc. are part of the *linking* format. While they *usually* are present in the fully-linked binary, they *can* be stripped.

The info that the loader needs to load the executable is stored as a table of *segments* (`Elf{36,64}_Phdr[]`).

> 2. If 1 is true, how to view such layout info in a ELF? objdump?

You can examine segments (and, if the optional section table is present, the mapping of sections to segments) with `readelf -Wl a.out`.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a bit and found something.

For 1. According [ELF format on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), there are `program headers` that record the address layout info.

For 2. `readelf` is a promising tool.